# xCode Dropbox (400) error

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox-api

Im getting an error trying to send a pdf to my personal dropbox account after logging in using the dropbox api iOS.

The error is as follows
"[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files_put/kDBRootAppFolder/Music.pdf - (400) Expected 'root' to be 'dropbox', 'sandbox', or 'auto', got u'kDBRootAppFolder'"

Here is what i've done to setup dropbox in my Xcode iOS project.

in my AppDelegate.m in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions i have the following:

```
DBSession *dbSession = [[DBSession alloc]
initWithAppKey:@"MYDROPBOXAPPKEY"
appSecret:@"MYDROPBOXAPPSECRET"
root:@"kDBRootAppFolder"]; // either kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox
[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
```

Also in AppDelegate.m i have added the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");
            // At this point you can start making API calls
        }
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"isDropboxLinked"
         object:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]]];


        return YES;
    }
    // Add whatever other url handling code is requires here if applicale
    return NO;
}
```

In my ViewController.m i have added the following and linked it to a UIButton

```
- (void)didPressLink {
    if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] link];
    }
}
```

I also have this in my viewDidLoad

```
self.restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
self.restClient.delegate = self;
```

I am able to hit my button, receive the Dropbox login screen and log in successfully with my personal account credentials.  I receive the following NSLog response when i login successfully "App linked successfully!"  see the code above that is in the AppDelegate.m that has this NSLog statement.  So far so good (i think)

Now i have a button which creates a pdf that i want to send to dropbox.  The pdf creates successfully.  and now i have this code to send the file to dropbox (filename is the name of my pdf which happens to be called Music.pdf in this scenario)

```
// Upload file to Dropbox
    NSString *destDir = @"/";
    [self.restClient uploadFile:fileName toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
```

This is where I'm getting the "DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/fileops/delete - (400) Expected 'root' to be 'dropbox', 'sandbox', or 'auto'; got 'kDBRootAppFolder'"  Why what am i missing?

NOTE: Once i've logged in successfully with my personal credentials and receive this error IF i got back to my AppDelegate.m and change the root from kDBRootAppFolder to sandbox and run the app again and try end send my Music.pdf file to dropbox it will work.  This isn't the solution because if i disconnect from my personal dropbox login and try and login again it will not "App linked successfully!" as indicated above if i leave root as kDBRootAppFolder.  Thoughts?........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're supplying kDBRootAppFolder as a string, and not the constant. The Dropbox SDK defines the kDBRootAppFolder constant for you to send the right  "root" to the Dropbox API itself.

So, this:

```
root:@"kDBRootAppFolder"];
```

should be:

```
root:kDBRootAppFolder];
```